# Add Delay to a view that joins two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have to create a view that basically queries table A, and ensures that the same item exists in table B, so if the item from table A does not exist in table B, a record is created in my view, and an external procedure triggers an alert. The problem that I have is that the record in table B is created sometimes, some seconds after the record in table A was created, and it trigger sometimes false alarms. So what I need is to add to the view creation some kind of delay in the view that waits at least 5 seconds to create the record if item in table A does not exist in table B before triggering the alert.

so if I have:

Table_A

| Item | Creation_Date |
| --- | --- |
| XY | 00:00:01 |

Table_B

| Item | Creation_Date |
| --- | --- |
| XY | 00:00:03 |

And I use this query to create a view in sql server:

```
select * from Table_A A
where A.Item not in (
select B.Item
from Table_B B)
where A.Creation_Date >= DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())
and B.Creation_Date >= DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())
```

If the alert procedure runs at 00:00:02 it will create the record in the view, and it will trigger the alarm.

How can I do to avoid this and to wait for some seconds to ensure that the record in Table_B is definitely not created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add another inequality condition to the `where` clause that excludes very recent records:

```
select * 
from Table_A A
where 
    A.Item not in (select B.Item from Table_B B)
    and A.Creation_Date >= DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())
    and A.Creation_Date <  DATEADD(second, -10, GETDATE())
```

Depending on how frequently your procedure runs, you might need to adjust the other bound as well:

```
. . .
and A.Creation_Date >= DATEADD(second, -10, DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE()))
and A.Creation_Date <  DATEADD(second, -10, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I noticed that I had an error on my query, what I do is to query the last 10 minutes of both tables, so I modified the last part (changing A for B) But I see your point and I think that it solves the case since the procedure runs every one minute. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try using *not exists* and include the time-delay required as part of the correlation criteria:

```
select * 
from Table_A a
where not exists (
  select * from Table_B b
    where a.Item = b.Item
    and a.Creation_Date < DateAdd(second, -5, GetDate())
);
```

Comment: Thanks, to include the time-delay I believe it solves it, what adds the not exists to the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - if it's *why* use `not exists` then this is always preferable over not in since it can be more efficient and is null-safe